# Query database for last modified date

Tags: php, database, wordpress, date

I am trying to query my Wordpress server to echo the date of the last modified post.
In this case the database name is local and I am checking the posts table.

My current code is close to what I need, it will display the date and time as `Y-m-d H:i` (2021-01-13 12:18)

```
<?php

global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM local LIKE 'wp_posts';");
foreach ($result as $data) {
    $updatetime = $data->Update_time;
}

$date = substr($updatetime, 0, -3);
echo $date;

?>
```

How do remove the time and display the date as `d.n.Y`?

Comment: Use the [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime) class. Create an object from your db value and format it to your liking.

Comment: Also, your question title suggests you have issues with fetching the needed value, when in fact you're only having trouble with formatting the value you already got from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `strtotime` for that....

```
$date = substr($updatetime, 0, -3); // assuming this produces 2021-01-13 12:18
echo date("d.m.Y", strtotime($date));
// 13.01.2021
```

Comment: perfect, this is the one!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incomplete:

```
<?php 
    $date = substr($updatetime, 0, -5);
        echo date("d.m.Y", strtotime($date));
    }
?>
```